# Excel Macro and command buttons

Tags: vba, outlook

I've created an UserForm in Outlook VBA and I have the option buttons set up to provide different options upon selection and everything works fine if I only go through once however,

Comment: I've tried few codes like this one:
`code`
Private Sub ClearAllOptionButtons()  
  Dim c As Control  
  For Each c In Me.Controls  
 If TypeOf c Is OptionButton Then c.Value = False  
  Next  
End Sub  
`code`

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Please [edit] your code into your original question - as you can see, it's quite difficult to read code in a comment. Additionally, taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] will give you a good feel for the place and help you get the most out of it.

Comment: Could you print the value of c. value?

Comment: Instead of  `c.Value = False`, can you try `c.Selected = False`?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this isn't actually possible. Once you've selected one radio button of a group, you will always have one selected. I believe that the only way to reset it to none selected would be to close the form and reload it.

Comment: And @FreeMan, I did not create any group; as far I remember. I just created 3 option button; and that's it. 

I'm just having a hard time believing that there's no way to resolve this!

Comment: What do you mean by "unselect this option **after the userform has been closed**"? Are you using the default instance of the `UserForm`? If so,just `Unload` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If I go back through a second time the option button from the previous run through is still selected.*

You're showing the form's *default instance*.

```
UserForm1.Show
```

What you're seeing means you have a transient, global-scope object that's keeping its state between calls.

If you want to "start clean" every time you show that form, you have two options - one would be to `Unload` the transient object when you're done with it:

```
UserForm1.Show
'do stuff
Unload UserForm1
```

Another (much cleaner IMO) would be to stop using that global-scope object, and create one that's locally scoped instead, with a much clearer lifespan:

```
With New UserForm1 ' object created here
    .Show
    'do stuff
End With ' object dies here
```

Or:

```
Dim frm As UserForm1
Set frm = New UserForm1 ' object created here
frm.Show
'do stuff
'frm object goes out of scope and is destroyed at the end of the procedure
```

Whether that breaks your other code, depends on how much of that other code is written against the form's default instance. You're using `Me` in the sample code you've provided, and that's a good sign: it means you've written the code against *whatever the current instance is*, as opposed to e.g. `For Each c In UserForm1.Controls`, which would be iterating the controls in the form's *default* instance - which may be in a different state than the controls in the *current* instance.

For more information about working with forms, see [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/), an article I wrote last year that explains in details what's wrong with the *default instance* approach.

Comment: I don't know what to say. Thank You Brother.

Comment: Who made whose day! Surely we could argue about that ;)